# Join laravel apenas 1 resultado

Tags: mysql, laravel

Alguem sabe como posso fazer um join retornar apenas o primeiro resultado ?

```
->join('addresses', function ($join) {
$join->on('s_complete_clients.id', '=', 'addresses.client_id')->limit(1);
})
```

Comment: Poderia explicar melhor é uma relação 1 para N? na sua pergunta! poderia colocar os `models` envolvidos.

Comment: A query.
https://gist.github.com/gmferreir1/918f2b103c51f5174896c0a71822c8ae